# Conflicto al hacer un git merge, HEAD y DEVELOP, ¿Cuál es cuál?

Tags: git, git-merge

Me he topado con un conflicto a la hora de hacer un *merge* de un *branch* a mi *develop*.

`git` no lo pudo resolver automáticamente y me he topado con que me ha editado el archivo incluyendo esto:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    some code 
=======
    some other code
>>>>>>> develop
```

He podido resolverlo manualmente editando el archivo y dándole `commit`, pero me ha quedado la duda, ¿Qué es `HEAD`? Asumo que **develop** tambien es el branch *develop* a donde le quedaría dar merge, ¿Es así?

Supongamos que mi *branch* se llame *foo* y que le deseo hacer un *merge* a *develop* (ambos localmente).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`HEAD` es el último commit de la rama desde donde hiciste `merge`

Entonces, si deseas dejar los cambios de la rama donde estabas situado cuando hiciste el merge, eliminas las líneas de `develop`. Si por el contrario deseas dejar los cambios de la rama `develop`, eliminas las líneas de `HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente **HEAD** es el encabezado a donde esta apuntando tu `working area`, para este caso, **HEAD** debería ser el código de origen y **DEVELOP** seria el código que esta en tu repositorio local.

Comment: suponiendo que mi branch se llama foo, head seria foo?

Comment: _Normalmente_ debería ser así.